# Quiver plot arrows in Matplotlib are ridiculously too large

Tags: python, matplotlib, physics

I was working on creating a python script that could model electric field lines, but the quiver plot comes out with arrows that are way too large. I've tried changing the units and the scale, but the documentation on matplotlib makes no sense too me... This seems to only be a major issue when there is only one charge in the system, but the arrows are still slightly oversized with any number of charges. The arrows tend to be oversized in all situations, but it is most evident with only one particle.

[image: Over sized arrows]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import sympy as sym
import astropy as astro

k = 9 * 10 ** 9


def get_inputs():
    inputs_loop = False
    while inputs_loop is False:
        """"
        get inputs
        """
        inputs_loop = True
        particles_loop = False
        while particles_loop is False:
            try:
                particles_loop = True
                """
                get n particles with n charges.
                """
                num_particles = int(raw_input('How many particles are in the system? '))
                parts = []
                for i in range(num_particles):
                    parts.append([float(raw_input("What is the charge of particle %s in Coulombs? " % (str(i + 1)))),
                                  [float(raw_input("What is the x position of particle %s? " % (str(i + 1)))),
                                   float(raw_input('What is the y position of particle %s? ' % (str(i + 1))))]])
            except ValueError:
                print 'Could not convert input to proper data type. Please try again.'
                particles_loop = False
    return parts
def vec_addition(vectors):
    x_sum = 0
    y_sum = 0
    for b in range(len(vectors)):
        x_sum += vectors[b][0]
        y_sum += vectors[b][1]
    return [x_sum,y_sum]

def electric_field(particle, point):
    if particle[0] > 0:
        """
        Electric field exitation is outwards

        If the x position of the particle is > the point, then a different calculation must be made than in not.
        """
        field_vector_x = k * (
        particle[0] / np.sqrt((particle[1][0] - point[0]) ** 2 + (particle[1][1] - point[1]) ** 2) ** 2) * \
                         (np.cos(np.arctan2((point[1] - particle[1][1]), (point[0] - particle[1][0]))))
        field_vector_y = k * (
        particle[0] / np.sqrt((particle[1][0] - point[0]) ** 2 + (particle[1][1] - point[1]) ** 2) ** 2) * \
                         (np.sin(np.arctan2((point[1] - particle[1][1]), (point[0] - particle[1][0]))))
        """
        Defining the direction of the components
        """
        if point[1] < particle[1][1] and field_vector_y > 0:
            print field_vector_y
            field_vector_y *= -1
        elif point[1] > particle[1][1] and field_vector_y < 0:
            print field_vector_y
            field_vector_y *= -1
        else:
            pass
        if point[0] < particle[1][0] and field_vector_x > 0:
            print field_vector_x
            field_vector_x *= -1
        elif point[0] > particle[1][0] and field_vector_x < 0:
            print field_vector_x
            field_vector_x *= -1
        else:
            pass
        """
        If the charge is negative
        """
    elif particle[0] < 0:
        field_vector_x = k * (
            particle[0] / np.sqrt((particle[1][0] - point[0]) ** 2 + (particle[1][1] - point[1]) ** 2) ** 2) * (
                             np.cos(np.arctan2((point[1] - particle[1][1]), (point[0] - particle[1][0]))))
        field_vector_y = k * (
            particle[0] / np.sqrt((particle[1][0] - point[0]) ** 2 + (particle[1][1] - point[1]) ** 2) ** 2) * (
                             np.sin(np.arctan2((point[1] - particle[1][1]), (point[0] - particle[1][0]))))
        """
        Defining the direction of the components
        """
        if point[1] > particle[1][1] and field_vector_y > 0:
            print field_vector_y
            field_vector_y *= -1
        elif point[1] < particle[1][1] and field_vector_y < 0:
            print field_vector_y
            field_vector_y *= -1
        else:
            pass
        if point[0] > particle[1][0] and field_vector_x > 0:
            print field_vector_x
            field_vector_x *= -1
        elif point[0] < particle[1][0] and field_vector_x < 0:
            print field_vector_x
            field_vector_x *= -1
        else:
            pass
    return [field_vector_x, field_vector_y]

def main(particles):
    """
    Graphs the electrical field lines.
    :param particles:
    :return:
    """
    """
    plot particle positions
    """
    particle_x = 0
    particle_y = 0
    for i in range(len(particles)):
        if particles[i][0]<0:
            particle_x = particles[i][1][0]
            particle_y = particles[i][1][1]
            plt.plot(particle_x,particle_y,'r+',linewidth=1.5)
        else:
            particle_x = particles[i][1][0]
            particle_y = particles[i][1][1]
            plt.plot(particle_x,particle_y,'r_',linewidth=1.5)
    """
    Plotting out the quiver plot.
    """
    parts_x = [particles[i][1][0] for i in range(len(particles))]
    graph_x_min = min(parts_x)
    graph_x_max = max(parts_x)
    x,y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(graph_x_min-(graph_x_max-graph_x_min),graph_x_max+(graph_x_max-graph_x_min)),
                      np.arange(graph_x_min-(graph_x_max-graph_x_min),graph_x_max+(graph_x_max-graph_x_min)))
    if len(particles)<2:
        for x_pos in range(int(particles[0][1][0]-10),int(particles[0][1][0]+10)):
            for y_pos in range(int(particles[0][1][0]-10),int(particles[0][1][0]+10)):
                vecs = []
                for particle_n in particles:
                    vecs.append(electric_field(particle_n, [x_pos, y_pos]))
                final_vector = vec_addition(vecs)
                distance = np.sqrt((final_vector[0] - x_pos) ** 2 + (final_vector[1] - y_pos) ** 2)
                plt.quiver(x_pos, y_pos, final_vector[0], final_vector[1], distance, angles='xy', scale_units='xy',
                           scale=1, width=0.05)
        plt.axis([particles[0][1][0]-10,particles[0][1][0]+10,
                  particles[0][1][0] - 10, particles[0][1][0] + 10])
    else:
        for x_pos in range(int(graph_x_min-(graph_x_max-graph_x_min)),int(graph_x_max+(graph_x_max-graph_x_min))):
            for y_pos in range(int(graph_x_min-(graph_x_max-graph_x_min)),int(graph_x_max+(graph_x_max-graph_x_min))):
                vecs = []
                for particle_n in particles:
                    vecs.append(electric_field(particle_n,[x_pos,y_pos]))
                final_vector = vec_addition(vecs)
                distance = np.sqrt((final_vector[0]-x_pos)**2+(final_vector[1]-y_pos)**2)
                plt.quiver(x_pos,y_pos,final_vector[0],final_vector[1],distance,angles='xy',units='xy')
        plt.axis([graph_x_min-(graph_x_max-graph_x_min),graph_x_max+(graph_x_max-graph_x_min),graph_x_min-(graph_x_max-graph_x_min),graph_x_max+(graph_x_max-graph_x_min)])
    plt.grid()
    plt.show()



g = get_inputs()
main(g)}
```

Comment: What values did you use in the `raw_input` requests to generate the displayed plot?

Comment: @Xukrao For the pictured example, my inputs were: 1 particle, 5 Coulombs, 0,0.

Comment: Please read [ask] and [mcve]: boil down your problem to a single, simple reproducible plot that produces your issue. It will be easier for you to see what's wrong, and it will be easier for others who try to help you here to play with your problem.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may set the scale such that it roughly corresponds to the `u` and `v` vectors.

```
plt.quiver(x_pos, y_pos, final_vector[0], final_vector[1], scale=1e9, units="xy")
```

This would result in something like this:

[image]

If I interprete it correctly, you want to draw the field vectors for point charges. Looking around at how other people have done that, one finds e.g. [this blog entry](http://scipython.com/blog/visualizing-a-vector-field-with-matplotlib/) by Christian Hill. He uses a `streamplot` instead of a `quiver` but we might take the code for calculating the field and replace the plot.

In any case, we do not want and do not need 100 different quiver plots, as in the code from the question, but only one single quiver plot that draws the entire field. We will of course run into a problem if we want to have the field vector's length denote the field strength, as the magnitude goes with the distance from the particles by the power of 3. A solution might be to scale the field logarithmically before plotting, such that the arrow lengths are still somehow visible, even at some distance from the particles. The `quiver` plot's scale parameter then can be used to adapt the lengths of the arrows such that they somehow fit to other plot parameters.

```
""" Original code by Christian Hill 
    http://scipython.com/blog/visualizing-a-vector-field-with-matplotlib/ 
    Changes made to display the field as a quiver plot instead of streamlines
"""
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.patches import Circle

def E(q, r0, x, y):
    """Return the electric field vector E=(Ex,Ey) due to charge q at r0."""
    den = ((x-r0[0])**2 + (y-r0[1])**2)**1.5
    return q * (x - r0[0]) / den, q * (y - r0[1]) / den

# Grid of x, y points
nx, ny = 32, 32
x = np.linspace(-2, 2, nx)
y = np.linspace(-2, 2, ny)
X, Y = np.meshgrid(x, y)


charges = [[5.,[-1,0]],[-5.,[+1,0]]]


# Electric field vector, E=(Ex, Ey), as separate components
Ex, Ey = np.zeros((ny, nx)), np.zeros((ny, nx))
for charge in charges:
    ex, ey = E(*charge, x=X, y=Y)
    Ex += ex
    Ey += ey

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

f = lambda x:np.sign(x)*np.log10(1+np.abs(x))

ax.quiver(x, y, f(Ex), f(Ey), scale=33)

# Add filled circles for the charges themselves
charge_colors = {True: 'red', False: 'blue'}
for q, pos in charges:
    ax.add_artist(Circle(pos, 0.05, color=charge_colors[q>0]))

ax.set_xlabel('$x$')
ax.set_ylabel('$y$')
ax.set_xlim(-2,2)
ax.set_ylim(-2,2)
ax.set_aspect('equal')
plt.show()
```

[image]

(Note that the field here is not normalized in any way, which should no matter for visualization at all.)

A different option is to look at e.g. [this code](https://github.com/tomduck/electrostatics/blob/master/examples/dipole.py) which also draws field lines from point charges.